# in javascript,why null !== undefined is true,but null == undefined also is true?

Tags: javascript, frontend, ecmascript-5

```js
console.log(undefined !== null);//true
console.log(undefined == null);//true
```

I can't undestand why undefined !==null,but i know undefined == null,because The language specification [explicitly says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3):

> If x is null and y is undefined, return true

Comment: Because `!==` is not the same as `!=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using strict equality for the first comparison and non-strict for the latter. You'll find that `undefined === null` is `false` as expected.

Comment: And similarly, with non-strict `!=` checking, `undefined != null` gets `false`. At least in this case, it's consistent, non-strict says they're equal (so `!=` gets `false`, `==` gets `true`), while strict says they're not equal (so `!==` gets `true` and `===` gets `false`).

Comment: @Marty thanks,i got it